# c# - Xamarin.Forms - Updating Entry Text not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an Entry like so:

```
<Entry x:Name="Customer_Name" WidthRequest="200" Placeholder="Customer_Name" />
```

and I am trying to update it when this method gets called:

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
{
     Customer_Name.Text = result.Trim();
}
```

But the text does not get updated....What am I doing wrong? Do I have to refresh the entry somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to execute UI updates on the UI thread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
  Customer_Name.Text = result.Trim();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! It works! Thanks! You have really helped me out today Jason, thank you.